# Guildhall reassigned: what are the implications?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

My people made too many `Petition`s one after another, and I didn't write them down on paper. There were some `Guildhall` requests, and, not knowing they can't be shared by more than one guild, I fumbled and reassigned/deleted some already existing `Guildhall`s. I don't remember which ones they were.

What are the implications of eliminating `Guildhall`s that way?

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Comment: When creating a meeting place and turning it into a guildhall, you can mouse-over the various available guilds and it should say if they have enough members in your fortress to qualify for a guildhall.